# Hadoop Map Reduce Query

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, tokenize

I was trying to use HADOOP MadReduce to calculate the sum of the weights of all
incoming edges for each node in a graph.The input is in a .tsv format and it looks like:

src tgt weight

X   102   1

X   200 1

X   123 5

Y   245 1

Y   101 1

Z   99  2

X   145 3

Y   24  1

A   21  5

.   .   .

.   .   .

The expected output is:

src SUM(weight)

X   10

Y   3

Z   2

A   5

.   .

.   .

I've used an example code of WordCount from hadoop (http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/hadoop-tutorial/CDH5/Hadoop-Tutorial/ht_wordcount1_source.html?scroll=topic_5_1) as the reference. I tried manipulating the code, but all my efforts ended up in vain.

I am pretty new to JAVA and HADOOP. I have shared my code. Kindly help me figure out what is wrong with the code.

Thanks.

Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

public class Task1 {

public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
private final static IntWritable value_parsed = new IntWritable();
private Text word = new Text();

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
String line = value.toString();
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
Text keys = new Text();
int sum;
while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
{
    tokenizer.nextToken();
    keys.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
    sum = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
    output.collect(keys, new IntWritable(sum));
}
}
}

public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException    {
    int sum = 0;
    while (values.hasNext()) {
    sum += values.next().get();
}
output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
JobConf conf = new JobConf(Task1.class);
conf.setJobName("Task1");

conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

JobClient.runJob(conf);
}
}
```

Comment: what are the results you get? coz as it seems you take the second column as your key and not the first....

Comment: Hi @NoamShaish   , I am getting the following output. The output is essentially the same as the input file, with an extra column added to the left, which I couldn't figure out yet what it is. 

0 51 11789 1

11 51 19403 1

22 51 29948 3

33 51 29949 1

44 51 29950 1

55 51 29951 1

66 151 130 51

77 151 152 79

88 151 429 20


Thank you for the help.

Comment: how is it the same if in the input there are X Y Z A?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your code little bit.

```
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        tokenizer.nextToken(); // this value is of first column
        keys.set(tokenizer.nextToken()); // this is wrong --you have to set
                                            // first column as key not
                                            // second column
        sum = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()); //  here 
                                                        // third column
        output.collect(keys, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
```

Hope this could help you